# replace the duplicate data in a row with NA except the first

Tags: r

I have a large data frame and am trying  to find duplicate elements in a row and to then replace all duplicated values with an empty string except the first time they appear in a row :

```
 df = matrix( c(2, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 3, 4),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow = TRUE) 

#  V1  V2  V3 
#1  2   4   2  
#2  1   5   1 
#3  3   3   4
```

I've tried this, but it replaces all of them with NA,

```
df[which(t(apply(df,1,function(x) 
     duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = T))), arr.ind = T)] <- ""
```

and the results is like this:

```
    V1  V2  V3 
 1  NA   4   NA  
 2  NA   5   NA 
 3  NA   NA  4
```

But I expect the results to be:

```
   V1  V2  V3 
1  2   4   NA  
2  1   5   NA 
3  3   NA  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` (row-wise) we can `replace` `duplicated` values in a row to `NA`.

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    4   NA
#[2,]    1    5   NA
#[3,]    3   NA    4
```